# ¿Validar ventana modal usando $this->validate en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Cordial saludo compañeros, tengo un formulario en el cual uso dos ventanas modales, uno para crear agentes y otro para editarlos, en mi controlador hago uso de $this->validate, para validar los campos del formulario, el problema que presento es que al existir un error de validacion en los formularios, el $this->validate me redirecciona de nuevo a la vista pero con la ventana modal cerrada,la idea es que al existir un error, me redireccione a la vista pero con el modal abierto para visualizar el error.
¿Como puedo hacer esto?, teniendo en cuenta que si hay un error en el modal de crear debe redireccionar a la vista con el modal de crear abierto y si hay un error en el modal de editar, debe redireccionar a la vista con el respectivo modal de editar abierto para visualizar los errores, por ahora tengo este condicional en la vista blade:

```
 {{-- Con este condicional abrimos el modal si hay un error de validacion en el backend --}} 
        @if($errors->any())
            <script>

             $('#createagent').modal('show');

            </script>
        @endif
```

Pero este no es muy optimo, ya que cuando ocurre cualquier error de validación , siempre me va a abrir el modal de crear. adjunto el codigo del controlador y la vista blade:

controlador:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Agent;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AgentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {


            $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:agents,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'

        ]);




        toastr()->success('Correctamente', 'Agente creado', [
            'timeOut' => 2000,
            'positionClass' => "toast-top-full-width",
            'progressBar' => false,
            'showDuration'=> 300,
            ]);

        //De esta forma se inserta tambien el id del usuario al que pertenece el agente en la bd
        auth()->user()->agent()->create($request->all());

        session_destroy();
        return redirect()->route('agent.list');
    }



    public function show()
    {


        //Con esto obtenemos todos los agentes que pertenezcan a la agencia autenticada
        $agent = Auth::user()->agent()->get();

        return view('AgentList', compact('agent'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Agent $agent)
    {
        //Consultamos el email perteneciente al agente
        $email = $agent->email;

        //Si el email que llega por request, es igual al de la base de datos
        if ($request->email == $email) {
            $request->request->remove('email');
        }

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'unique:agents'
        ]);

        toastr()->info('Correctamente', 'Agente editado', [
            'timeOut' => 2000,
            'positionClass' => "toast-top-full-width",
            'progressBar' => false,
            'showDuration'=> 300,
            ]);

            $agent->fill($request->all());
            $agent->save();





        return redirect()->route('agent.list');
    }

    public function destroy(Agent $agent)
    {
        toastr()->error('Correctamente', 'Agente eliminado', [
            'timeOut' => 2000,
            'positionClass' => "toast-top-full-width",
            'progressBar' => false,
            'showDuration'=> 300,
            ]);

        $agent->delete();

        return redirect()->route('agent.list');
    }

    public function assign(Agent $agent)
    {

    //Con esto obtenemos todos los clientes que pertenezcan a la agencia autenticada
        $client = Auth::user()->client()->get();

        //Obtenemos los clientes que ya estan asignados al agente
        $clients = $agent->clients;

        return view('AssignClients', compact('agent', 'client', 'clients'));
    }

    public function saveclient(Request $request, Agent $agent)
    {
        toastr()->success('Correctamente', 'Cliente asignado correctamente', [
            'timeOut' => 2000,
            'positionClass' => "toast-top-full-width",
            'progressBar' => false,
            'showDuration'=> 300,
            ]);

        //El metodo attach guarda los datos en la tabla pivote, pero permite la duplicidad de datos
        // $agent->clients()->attach($request->clients);

        //El metodo syncWithoutDetaching evita la duplicidad de datos en la tabla pivote
        $agent->clients()->syncWithoutDetaching($request->clients);



        return redirect()->route('assign.client', $agent);
    }

    public function detachClient(Request $request, Agent $agent, $client)
    {
        toastr()->error('Correctamente', 'Cliente desvinculado', [
            'timeOut' => 2000,
            'positionClass' => "toast-top-full-width",
            'progressBar' => false,
            'showDuration'=> 300,
            ]);

        $agent->clients()->detach($client);

        return redirect()->route('assign.client', $agent);
    }
}
```

vista blade:

```
 @extends('layouts.app') 

 @section('content')


<div class="container" style="text-align:right">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createagent">
     Añadir agente
 </button>

</div>
<br>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Modal para agregar agente -->
    <form action="{{ route('agent.create') }}" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="modal fade" id="createagent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Crear agente</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="container-fluid">


                            <span class="input-group-text"><strong>Nombre del agente</strong></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del agente" required><br> {{ $errors->first('name') }}

                            <span class="input-group-text"><strong>Correo del agente</strong></span>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Ingrese el correo del agente" required><br> {{ $errors->first('email') }}

                            <span class="input-group-text"><strong>Contraseña del agente</strong></span>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Ingrese la contraseña del agente" required><br> {{ $errors->first('password') }}



                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Crear</button>
                    </div>


                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
    <div class="container-fluid">


        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>

                    <th scope="col">NOMBRE</th>
                    <th scope="col">CORREO</th>
                    <th scope="col">CONTRASEÑA</th>
                    <th scope="col">ACCIONES</th>



                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($agent as $agente)
                <tr>

                    <td>{{ $agente->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $agente->email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $agente->password }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('assign.client',$agente->id) }}"> <button class="btn btn-success">Asignar clientes</button> </a>

                        <button type="button" data-id="{{ $agente->id }}" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editar_{{$agente->id}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </button>

                        <!-- Modal para editar agente -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="editar_{{$agente->id}}" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <form action="{{ route('agent.update',$agente->id) }}" method="POST">
                                {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('PUT') }}
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Editar agente</h4>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="container-fluid">

                                                <input type="text" name="id" value="{{ $agente->id }}" hidden>

                                                <span class="input-group-text"><strong>Nombre del agente</strong></span>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="{{ $agente->name }}" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del agente" required><br> {{ $errors->first('name') }}

                                                <span class="input-group-text"><strong>Correo del agente</strong></span>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="{{ $agente->email }}" placeholder="Ingrese el correo del agente" required><br> {{ $errors->first('email') }}

                                                <span class="input-group-text"><strong>Contraseña del agente</strong></span>
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" value="{{ $agente->password }}" placeholder="Ingrese la contraseña del agente" required><br> {{ $errors->first('password') }}



                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {{-- boton para eliminar --}}
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('agent.destroy', $agente->id) }}" style="display:inline">
                        {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro de querer eliminar este agente?')">
                                <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        {{-- Con este condicional abrimos el modal si hay un error de validacion en el backend --}} 
        @if($errors->any())
            <script>

             $('#createagent').modal('show');

            </script>
        @endif 


    </div>


@stop
```

¿Alguna idea de como puedo solucionar esto?, ¿es posible retornar un valor especifico cuando el $this validate encuentra un error?, para de esta forma usar un valor que diferencie, si el error viene de la funcion crear o editar y asi usar un condicional en la vista blade para abrir el respecitvo modal?.

Comment: en lo personal uso jquery y javascript al hacer el boton submit valido todo y luego inserto o actualizo datos..

Comment: De esa forma tambien puedes validar el unique? como lo harias?

Comment: a que te refieres con el unique ?

Comment: Cuando uso $this->validate en el controlador, uso la regla unique para evitar que se creen agentes con un email que ya este registrado en base de datos

Comment: cuando tu validas por jquery  o javascript alli ya verificas que todo sea correcto de tu formulario luego de ello mandas a donde desees(model...view..controller) para insertar o actualizar ya no necesitas hacer otro validate...xq ya lo validaste con jquery/javascript

Comment: aqui tienes un ejemplo de ello: https://appdividend.com/2018/02/08/laravel-ajax-validation-tutorial-scratch/

Comment: en el caso del validate.. ya no lo usarias.. primero harias una consulta de si existe ese email...a la base de datos desde ajax.. si existe este email en ese instante le notificas al usuario .. y le das la opcion de modificar o ingresar otro email

Comment: debe de existir alguna manera de hacerlo con this validate, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buenos dia lo que usted quiere es realiza un crud con ajax y con modal, lo bueno es que tengo un buen ejemplo en el siguiente link, no le puedo publicar todo el codigo por ser demadiado largo, pero le voy a pasar un proyecto que usted necesita, la ventaja es que solo necesito utilizar un formulario en vez de dos
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/icxmg95nnwskv5k/AAAqlGD09mp4mFmdRs2Qlo4na?dl=0

configure los bontones para que guarde los datos

```
<button class="mass_show-modal btn btn-danger"
        data-id="{{ $lists->id}}"
        data-nombre="{{ $lists->nombre}}"
        data-comuna_id="{{ $lists->comuna_id}}"
        data-municipios_id="{{ $lists->municipios_id}}"
        data-created_at="{{ $lists->created_at}}"
        data-updated_at="{{ $lists->updated_at}}"
><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Eliminar</button>
```

en este punto se obtiene los datos de campo

```
$(document).on('click', '.mass_show-modal', function() {
            $('.modal-descripcion').text('Vista de los Datos');
            $('#msdelete').text(' ');

            $('#id_mass').val($(this).data('id'));
$('#nombre_mass').val($(this).data('nombre'));
$('#comuna_id_mass').val($(this).data('comuna_id'));
$('#municipios_id_mass').val($(this).data('municipios_id'));
$('#created_at_mass').val($(this).data('created_at'));
$('#updated_at_mass').val($(this).data('updated_at'));
;


            $('#massModal').modal('show');
            $('#acciones').attr('class', 'btn btn-info hibe');
            $('#acciones').text('Visible');
            $('#acciones').attr('disabled');

        });
```

y en el modal se utiliza la siguiente propiedad

```
<div id="massModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-descripcion"></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```